# Vuetify how to add/remove rule dynamically

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify validation, and i have three date fields: **Month**, **From**, **To**. I need to add required rule according to the following:

- If **Month** selected - **From** and **To** not required.
- If any of **From** or **To** selected - **Month** not required.

I tried computed() method, to check if **From** or **To** are null, but it seems like :rules set once, and then not change.

```
computed: {
    monthRules() {
      return this.searchForm.from ? [] : [factory.required()];
    },
```

Here's some code

```
<date-field
  ref="month"
  v-model="searchForm.month"
  :rules="monthRules"
>
</date-field>

<date-field
  ref="from"
  v-model="searchForm.from"
  @input="validateTo"
  :rules="fromRules"
>
</date-field>
    
<date-field
  ref="to"
  v-model="searchForm.to"
  :rules="toRules"
>
</date-field>
```

```
monthRules: [factory.required()],
fromRules: [],
toRules: [
  *some rules from factory here*
],
```

#### factory

```
required() {
    return v => !!v || 'Field is required';
},
```

Is it possible to dynamically build an array of rules? Or is there a better way

Comment: Simplest of solution would be to use if-else check during render..

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear on Vuetify rules as I think it's better to use a specialized library like [vee-validate](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/) which already has a ton of pre-defined rules, for something like this. As for the dynamic rules, the best way to go about would be to use an object binding like so:

```js
:rules="{
  required: requiredBool
 }"
```

Where `requireBool` is your computed property. Again, as I said, I am not very familiar with `Vuetify rules`, but this works like a charm with Vee-Validate.